# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty} x^3 / (e^x-1)\,\mathrm{d}x = \pi^4 / 15$

Tags: integration

I tried to solve the following by the $u(x)v(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ method but am stuck at the very first step that I can't take any one of the two as $u$ or $v$.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$$

What is the step by step process to solve this integration?

Comment: Took a stab at editing for you. Please confirm this is your question.

Comment: Thanks for editing,Sir.

Comment: See this previous answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99843/contour-integral-for-x3-ex-1

Comment: $\Gamma(4)\zeta(4)$

Comment: It is equal to $\Gamma (4) \zeta (4) =3! \frac {\pi^4} {90}=\frac {\pi^4} {15}$.