# Finding a definite integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So, I was solving a physics problem, whereby I encountered a definite integral which looks like

$$\int_0^∞ {\frac {x^5}{e^x-1}} \,dx$$
I have no idea how to tackle this integral. I had found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99843/contour-integral-for-x3-ex-1) on the site, the solutions of which I find beyond my understanding. If possible can anyone suggest some elementary way to solve this integral, I am not quite familiar with stuffs like contour integral. Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you men by “[similar question][1]”?

Comment: Welcome. This reminds me of classic zeta/eta integrals involving the gamma function.

Comment: @AnotherUser I am sorry. I am unable to edit the link in a proper manner.

Comment: Not sure why but removing the gratuitous <p> at the start of the post fixed it.